# Why my QtRPT project file is not running in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have QtRPTProject to run in the QtCreator but It is showing errors like      " Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?" and "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script" while building.Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script

This means that the module [Qt Script](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html) is not installed.
This module has been deprecated and is not installed by default, you have to opt-in.

The exact procedure on how to install it depends on how you installed Qt in the first place. If you used the online installer, it is just a matter of running the "Maintenance Tool" and checking the Qt Script checkbox.

> Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

This means that Qt Creator cannot find the c++ compiler.
That means that you have not installed a compiler, or not configured Qt Creator correctly.

Again the exact procedure depends on your system and which compiler you want to use. If you are on Windows, the Qt Maintenance Tool offers to install MinGW for your. Like for Qt Script it is just a matter of checking the right checkbox. Be sure to select the MinGW version that matches the version of Qt you selected.

If you need more help, please edit your question and add details about your system and your current installation.